# What ist the correct srcset sizes order and media query

Tags: html, responsive, srcset

I'm trying to achieve these sizes for my srcset image:

- Desktop (min-width: 1024px): 100vw
- Tablet (min-width: 768px): 150vw
- Phone+Other: 200vw

(It's supposed to be larger than the screen since it's animated).
But what is the correct order within the sizes attribute?

This did not work (way larger image was loaded):

`sizes="(min-width: 768px) 150vw, (min-width: 1024px) 100vw, 200vw"`

This seems to work for now:

`sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 100vw, (min-width: 768px) 150vw, 200vw"`

On my 1440px Macbook Air, the availble 1440px image is not loaded but instead a larger 1700px version. But this might be a Browser decision.

But in theory `min-width: 786px` is also true for `min-width: 1024px`, as a screen larger than 1024px is also larger than 768px. In CSS the last true argument is used (in this case this would be the wrong 768px size), but what about HTML and srcset?

Do I need to do something like this:

`sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 100vw, (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) 150vw, 200vw"`

But I have never seen that before....

Comment: Can you provide a full example with the `1440px` image not being loaded correctly?

Comment: It seemed to be a browser cache problem. A larger Version was already in my browser cache... Works now, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser selects the first size for which the query matches. So your example could either be (as your working example):

```
(min-width: 1024px) 100vw, (min-width: 768px) 150vw, 200vw
```

or the other way round:

```
(max-width: 767px) 200vw, (max-width: 1023px) 150vw, 100vw
```

If your browser window is `1440px` wide and the pixel density of your screen is `1x` an available `1440px`-image should be loaded by the browser (unless it has already a larger version in the cache).